# Angular, ng-grid and dynamically populating the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to populate an ng-grid after an AJAX call is returned.  The user presses the button to perform a query, and the result is intended to be shown in a grid.

My html is:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"  ></div>
```

And my js is:

```
app.queryCallback = function(graph) {
    var results = graph.toJSON();
    var columns = [ns.gtry("hasRank"), ns.gtry("score"), ns.gtry("ks_up"), ns.gtry("ks_down")];
    var names = ["Has Rank", "Score", "up", "down"];
    $scope.queryData = [];
    $.each(results, function(key, values) {
        var row = {};
        $.each(values, function(uri, dict){
            $.each(columns, function(i, column){
                if (column == uri) {
                    row[names[i]] = dict[0]['value'];
                }
            });
        });
        $scope.queryData.push(row);
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = {data : 'queryData'};
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

and my controller is set up as follow:

```
goiapp.controller('goip', function ($scope) {
var app = this;
```

However, the grid isn't shown, and with the chrome debugger, I have verified that app.queryData has the correct objects.

Comment: Try defining `$scope.queryData` in your controller, outside the callback.